# How do i get my UILoader to play an .SWF once then disappear?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, list, uiloader

How do i get my UILoader to play a .swf file once then disappear until called upon again?

I am creating a guitar tutorial app that shows you chords and the transitions between them. to display the chords I'm using standard Flash graphics and for the transitions i am using a UI Loader to display the .swf files for instance, on the C chord frame, the fingers are in position and the UI Loader is a layer on top of it, when the chord transition is selected from the list component it loads the chordtransition.swf.

The problem is that once the swf is loaded it plays on loop, ive added "stop();" in many different places as people suggest and it doesn't make a difference.

I would like to be able to click "C-D" on the component list then for the .swf to play once then disappear.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

A strategically placed stop() should work (last frame on the timeline in the swf). You'll need to stop the right movieclip - if your movie has nested clips you might be stopping the wrong clip.

However, creating multiple swf's just to show different chords looks like overkill to me.

Create clips showing all chords on the main timeline, and add frame labels to indicate where they start and put stop() at the end of every chord animation (are you using animations?).

Use movieclipWithChords.gotoAndPlay("chord_C");
If you are not using animations you can use movieclipWithChords.gotoAndStop("chord_C");

Of course you can also create labels like 'C' and 'D', and use those as a direct mapping of the chords.

Update: After reading your question again I realize you are actually showing clips of a transition from one chord to another. In that case you can still use my suggestion as above, only your labels will not be for the individual chords, but for the chord transitions e.g. 'transition_C-D' or 'transition_G-B'.